# Automating installation of tripwire via python in Linux

Tags: python, linux, apt-get, apt

I am trying to automate installation of tripwire via apt-get through Python's subprocess module in Ubuntu Linux. The problem I have is that during the installation process, Tripwire is prompting me for Postfix mail configuration, setting site.key and local.key through different set of configuration pages (see picture attached) which appear after apt-get has installed.

How can I use subprocess module to interact with these pages?

```
from subprocess import *
p=Popen("apt-get install tripwire",stdout=PIPE,stdin=PIPE,stderr=PIPE,shell=True)
p.communicate(input="Y\n") # Y = Yes to confirm installation of the package through apt-get
```

I tried to use "stdin=PIPE", but there are a couple of challenges with interacting with these terminal pages:

1. These pages appear after the package is downloaded and is being
   configured, so I have to implement some kind of delay for the
   page to appear
2. Also, I need to implement up and down arrow keys to choose the various options.

Thanks

John

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Launch the install with auto-confirm and quiet mode enabled and set [this flag](https://serverfault.com/questions/227190/how-do-i-ask-apt-get-to-skip-any-interactive-post-install-configuration-steps):

`export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive`

`apt-get install -y -q tripwire`

This way you won't need to communicate with the post-install config.
You can also pass along pre-exising `config` files with `-c` (or specify configuration options with `-o`).

I would probably try:

```
from subprocess import call
p = call(["apt-get", "install", "-y", "-q", "-c", "config.cfg", "tripwire", shell=False])
```

Comment: Thanks Chris... however, I still get a tripwire configuration dialog box asking me whether I wish to create site key passphrase when I use auto-confirm and quiet mode.

Comment: Thanks, Chris... this definitely works. Initially it did not work, until I realized that I had set the env variable in the wrong context (normal user rather than root).... so I "sudo su" and executed the export command. Then I exited su, ran  sudo apt-get command (as apt-get typically installs with imitating root) and installed tripwire... that worked without showing me any front-end terminal screens... thanks.