# How to handle interactive apt-get installation with python 3.6 subprocess.Popen() function?

Tags: python, subprocess

**Issue:** I wrote the following python 3.6 script using the `subprocess.Popen()` function to run the linux `apt-get` command to install debian packages. I encountered a package, `ubuntu-restricted-extras`,  that required user interaction during the installation process. These interactions caused my script to hang.

**Question:** How can my script avoid hanging during interactive installation and complete the package installation? Interactively where possible. Below is my script. It was tested on Ubuntu 18.04.

```
import subprocess

def call_subprocess_Popen( cmd, cwd=None ):
    ''' Execute a command in BASH. kwargs: "cmd" is a list.'''
    with subprocess.Popen( cmd, bufsize=1, universal_newlines=True, cwd=cwd,
                           stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
                           ) as result:
        for line in result.stdout:
            print( line, end='' )
        for line in result.stderr:
            print( line, end='' )
    print( result.returncode )
    print( result.args )
    if result.returncode != 0:
        raise subprocess.CalledProcessError( result.returncode, result.args )
    else:
        return True

def pkexec_apt_get_y_install( packages ):
    print( f'\npkexec apt_get_y_install ....' )
    cmd = [ 'pkexec', 'apt-get', '-y', 'install' ]
    cmd.extend( packages )
    print( f'cmd = {cmd}' )
    if call_subprocess_Popen( cmd ):
        return True
    else:
        return False

apps = [ 'ubuntu-restricted-extras' ]
pkexec_apt_get_y_install( apps )
```

**Revised script to implement `DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive`:**

```
import subprocess, os

def call_subprocess_Popen( cmd, cwd=None, env=None, shell=False ):
    ''' Execute a command in BASH. kwargs: "cmd" is a list.'''
    with subprocess.Popen( cmd, bufsize=1, universal_newlines=True, 
                           stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
                           cwd=cwd, env=env, shell=shell ) as result:
        for line in result.stdout:
            print( line, end='' )
        for line in result.stderr:
            print( line, end='' )
    print( result.returncode )
    print( result.args )
    if result.returncode != 0:
        raise subprocess.CalledProcessError( result.returncode, result.args )
    else:
        return True

def pkexec_apt_get_y_install( packages, env=None, shell=False ):
    print( f'\npkexec apt_get_y_install ....' )
    if shell:
        cmd = 'pkexec apt-get -y -q install ' + ' '.join(apps)
    else:
        cmd = [ 'pkexec', 'apt-get', '-y', '-q', 'install' ]
        cmd.extend( packages )
    print( f'cmd = {cmd}' )
    if call_subprocess_Popen( cmd, env=env, shell=shell ):
        return True
    else:
        return False

apps = [ 'ubuntu-restricted-extras' ]
my_env = os.environ.copy()
my_env["DEBIAN_FRONTEND"] = "noninteractive"
pkexec_apt_get_y_install( apps, env=my_env )
```

**Associate Error:**

```
pkexec apt_get_y_install ....
cmd = ['pkexec', 'apt-get', '-y', '-q', 'install', 'ubuntu-restricted-extras']
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  libllvm7
Use 'apt autoremove' to remove it.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  cabextract gstreamer1.0-fluendo-mp3 gstreamer1.0-libav
  gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly gstreamer1.0-vaapi i965-va-driver liba52-0.7.4
  libaacs0 libass9 libavcodec-extra libavcodec-extra57 libavfilter6
  libavformat57 libavresample3 libavutil55 libbdplus0 libbluray2 libbs2b0
  libchromaprint1 libcrystalhd3 libdvdnav4 libdvdread4 libflite1 libgme0
  libgsm1 libgstreamer-plugins-bad1.0-0 libmpeg2-4 libmspack0 libmysofa0
  libnorm1 libopenjp2-7 libopenmpt0 libpgm-5.2-0 libpostproc54 librubberband2
  libshine3 libsidplay1v5 libsnappy1v5 libsoxr0 libssh-gcrypt-4 libswresample2
  libswscale4 libva-drm2 libva-wayland2 libva-x11-2 libva2 libvo-amrwbenc0
  libx264-152 libx265-146 libxvidcore4 libzmq5 libzvbi-common libzvbi0
  mesa-va-drivers ttf-mscorefonts-installer ubuntu-restricted-addons unrar
  va-driver-all
Suggested packages:
  gstreamer1.0-vaapi-doc i965-va-driver-shaders libbluray-bdj
  firmware-crystalhd libdvdcss2 sidplay-base
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  cabextract gstreamer1.0-fluendo-mp3 gstreamer1.0-libav
  gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly gstreamer1.0-vaapi i965-va-driver liba52-0.7.4
  libaacs0 libass9 libavcodec-extra libavcodec-extra57 libavfilter6
  libavformat57 libavresample3 libavutil55 libbdplus0 libbluray2 libbs2b0
  libchromaprint1 libcrystalhd3 libdvdnav4 libdvdread4 libflite1 libgme0
  libgsm1 libgstreamer-plugins-bad1.0-0 libmpeg2-4 libmspack0 libmysofa0
  libnorm1 libopenjp2-7 libopenmpt0 libpgm-5.2-0 libpostproc54 librubberband2
  libshine3 libsidplay1v5 libsnappy1v5 libsoxr0 libssh-gcrypt-4 libswresample2
  libswscale4 libva-drm2 libva-wayland2 libva-x11-2 libva2 libvo-amrwbenc0
  libx264-152 libx265-146 libxvidcore4 libzmq5 libzvbi-common libzvbi0
  mesa-va-drivers ttf-mscorefonts-installer ubuntu-restricted-addons
  ubuntu-restricted-extras unrar va-driver-all
Preconfiguring packages ...
0 upgraded, 59 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/28.9 MB of archives.
After this operation, 105 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Selecting previously unselected package libmspack0:amd64.
(Reading database ... 
(Reading database ... 5%
(Reading database ... 10%
(Reading database ... 15%
(Reading database ... 20%
(Reading database ... 25%
(Reading database ... 30%
(Reading database ... 35%
(Reading database ... 40%
(Reading database ... 45%
(Reading database ... 50%
(Reading database ... 55%
(Reading database ... 60%
(Reading database ... 65%
(Reading database ... 70%
(Reading database ... 75%
(Reading database ... 80%
(Reading database ... 85%
(Reading database ... 90%
(Reading database ... 95%
(Reading database ... 100%
(Reading database ... 203579 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../00-libmspack0_0.6-3ubuntu0.3_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libmspack0:amd64 (0.6-3ubuntu0.3) ...
Selecting previously unselected package cabextract.
Preparing to unpack .../01-cabextract_1.6-1.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking cabextract (1.6-1.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package ttf-mscorefonts-installer.
Preparing to unpack .../02-ttf-mscorefonts-installer_3.6ubuntu2_all.deb ...
[?1049h[22;0;0t[1;24r[4l[?25l(B[m[37m[40m[1;24r[H[2J[1;1H[97m[45m[K
[K
[K
[K
[K
[K
[K
[K
[K
[K
[K
[K
[K
[K
[K
[K
[K
[K
[K
[K
[K
[K
[K
```

**Arne's Solution:**

```
import os
from subprocess import run, PIPE, STDOUT


def apt_install(pkgs, verbose=True):
    cmd = ['pkexec', 'apt-get', 'install', '-y'] + pkgs
    result = run(
        cmd,
        stdout=PIPE,
        stderr=STDOUT,
        encoding='utf8',
        env={**os.environ, 'DEBIAN_FRONTEND': 'noninteractive'}
    )
    if verbose:
        print("".join(result.stdout))
        print(f"Executed command: {result.args}")
    result.check_returncode()

def setup_msttcorefonts():
    cmd = 'echo msttcorefonts msttcorefonts/{}-mscorefonts-eula {} | debconf-set-selections'
    run(cmd.format("present", "note ''"), shell=True)
    run(cmd.format("accepted", "select true"), shell=True)


# testing with configured licenses, one simple and one complicated package
setup_msttcorefonts()
apt_install(['curl', 'ubuntu-restricted-extras'])
```

**Results from using Arne's Solution:**

```
$ python3.6 Q2_2018_07_14_v1.py 
debconf: DbDriver "passwords" warning: could not open /var/cache/debconf/passwords.dat: Permission denied
debconf: DbDriver "config": could not write /var/cache/debconf/config.dat-new: Permission denied
debconf: DbDriver "passwords" warning: could not open /var/cache/debconf/passwords.dat: Permission denied
debconf: DbDriver "config": could not write /var/cache/debconf/config.dat-new: Permission denied
Error executing command as another user: Request dismissed

Executed command: ['pkexec', 'apt-get', 'install', '-y', 'curl', 'ubuntu-restricted-extras']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Q2_2018_07_14_v1.py", line 27, in <module>
    apt_install(['curl', 'ubuntu-restricted-extras'])
  File "Q2_2018_07_14_v1.py", line 17, in apt_install
    result.check_returncode()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 389, in check_returncode
    self.stderr)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['pkexec', 'apt-get', 'install', '-y', 'curl', 'ubuntu-restricted-extras']' returned non-zero exit status 126.
```

Comment: What kind of interactions??  Y/N or does it require a directory?

Comment: @ChrisMarotta You need to say yes to a license

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Running an uninterrupted installation on ubuntu

The installation of `ubuntu-restricted-extras` requires you to accept its EULA license, which is interactive in order to ensure that a person does the accepting and not a script. So `apt-get` is behaving correct here by not providing an option to bypass something that is essentially a contract.

But as usual, there is some code that you can run which will skip the interactive step and install `ubuntu-restricted-extras` anyway.

If you're lucky, setting `noninteractive` will just work:

```sh
DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get -y install ubuntu-restricted-extras
```

Or you can write the info that would be set on see/accept by hand:

```sh
echo msttcorefonts msttcorefonts/present-mscorefonts-eula note '' | debconf-set-selections
echo msttcorefonts msttcorefonts/accepted-mscorefonts-eula select true | debconf-set-selections
apt-get -y install ubuntu-restricted-extras
```

---

#### As a python script

The following will show how a more or less minimal implementation of an `apt` installer utility could look like. I'd use `subprocess.run` instead of `subprocess.Popen` because it has a nicer interface, as long as you don't you need a very fine-grained control over the process I'd recommend you do the same.

Unless you have accepted the EULA at some other point already, skipping over it with `noninteractive` will cause your program to print the following lines somewhere in the middle of its run:

```
mscorefonts-eula license could not be presented 
try 'dpkg-reconfigure debconf' to select a frontend other than noninteractive 
[...]
user did not accept the mscorefonts-eula license
```

Depending on how exactly your machine is set up, the package might then have been installed but not configured correctly. The `ttf-mscorefonts-installer` will only run if it was accepted properly before installation, which is why I also had to run an accepting-function before the installation step in all of my tests:

```py
import os
import sys
from subprocess import run


def apt_install(pkgs):
    cmd = ['pkexec', 'apt-get', 'install', '-y'] + pkgs
    print('Running command: {}'.format(' '.join(cmd)))
    result = run(
        cmd,
        stdout=sys.stdout,
        stderr=sys.stderr,
        encoding='utf8',
        env={**os.environ, 'DEBIAN_FRONTEND': 'noninteractive'}
    )
    result.check_returncode()

def accept_eula():
    cmd = 'echo msttcorefonts msttcorefonts/{}-mscorefonts-eula {} | pkexec debconf-set-selections'
    run(cmd.format("present", "note ''"), stdout=sys.stdout, stderr=sys.stderr, shell=True)
    run(cmd.format("accepted", "select true"), stdout=sys.stdout, stderr=sys.stderr, shell=True)


# testing with configured licenses, one simple and one complicated package
accept_eula()
apt_install(['curl', 'ubuntu-restricted-extras'])
```

Running it like this finally resulted in a properly configured installation that exited with this output:

```
[...]
All done, no errors.
Extracting cabinet: /var/lib/update-notifier/package-data-downloads/partial/webdin32.exe
  extracting fontinst.exe
  extracting Webdings.TTF
  extracting fontinst.inf
  extracting Licen.TXT

All done, no errors.
All fonts downloaded and installed.
Setting up ttf-mscorefonts-installer (3.6ubuntu2) ...
```

Comment: `sudo DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get -y install ubuntu-restricted-extras' works on terminal. But I could not get it to work in Python. Uploading my revised script and error next. Could you have a look and tell me how to overcome the issue?

Comment: I had also tried to added the `-q` option on `apt` as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38419752/5722359) but it did not work. Running above script via idle-python3.6 in Ubuntu18.04. Revised script and error uploaded.The execution just hangs.

Comment: Appreciate you amend your answer to show how to implement your solutions in Python3.6 and `subprocess.Popen()`. Thanks.

Comment: Sure, just need a bit to set it up and test on my end.

Comment: I found a way? **Step1:** Replace `my_env = os.environ.copy()` and  `my_env["DEBIAN_FRONTEND"] = "noninteractive"` with  `my_env = {'DEBIAN_FRONTEND': 'noninteractive'}`. **Step2:** Run this revised script in a terminal. The installation will initially start and then pause. At this point, after I pressed the [Return] key in the keyboard, the installation resumed until completion. **Problem:** This same script would hang `idle-python3.6`. This is because, I am unable to issue the keyboard [Return] key. Any idea on how to avoid having to press the [Return] key?

Comment: Correction. I had to press `y` followed by the [Return] key to accept ttf-mscorefonts-installer's terms and condition.

Comment: @SunBear I think it's now in a usable state. Can you replicate it on your end?

Comment: Experiencing font download issues. `ttf-mscorefonts-installer: downloading http://downloads.sourceforge.net/corefonts/andale32.exe
Err:1 http://downloads.sourceforge.net/corefonts/andale32.exe
  Redirection from https to 'http://downloads.sourceforge.net/mirrorproblem?failedmirror=nchc.dl.sourceforge.net' is forbidden [IP: xxx.xx.xx.xx xxx]`

Comment: Don't think issue is related to your script? Maybe my IP has been temporarily blocked from downloading? Btw, did you test your script in a terminal or idle-python3.6?

Comment: Yeah, it executed fine for me on ubuntu 18.04 and python 3.6. I ran it in a terminal, and your error looks like a network issue. Do the commands work when executed as the original bash commands from a terminal?

Comment: I have attached my version of your script in my question. Please check. Below it, I also showed the corresponding terminal msgs. After I saw the `debconf` permission denied warnings, I clicked `Cancel` in `pkexec` to terminate the installation. How do I avoid the `debconf` warnings or should I ignore them? Another question: Why must we use `shell=True` in `setup_msttcorefonts()`?

Comment: `shell=True` means that the command is submitted to the process as a single string instead of an argument list. It's preferable to work with `shell=False`, the default, but for things like output redirection (in this case my usage of `|`), it is necessary - it is not an argument, so you can't express it with an argument list.

Comment: the `debconf` warnings are a problem. I tested my code in a docker container, where I am `root` by default and don't get these permission issues. You have to run the `dbconf` commands with `pkexec` as well, I'll update my answer... I forgot to add it to the python install script as well.

Comment: Like this? `cmd = 'pkexec echo msttcorefonts msttcorefonts/{}-mscorefonts-eula {} | debconf-set-selections'` I tried this but still received the same `debconf` permission denied warnings.

Comment: Yup, that's what I meant. That it doesn't work is too bad.. any chance to use sudo instead of pkexec?

Comment: It should be `cmd = 'echo msttcorefonts msttcorefonts/{}-mscorefonts-eula {} | pkexec debconf-set-selections'`.  This worked. I made the mistake. `debconf` needed `pkexec` but not the `echo`. Why must we use `shell=True` in `setup_msttcorefonts()` but not for `apt_install()`? Also, my 1st version had used `subprocess.run()`. However, I could not get it to print `result.stdout` line by line as they appear. Presently, your script prints `result.stdout` when all is done. Can you make your script output `result.stdout` line by line as I did with `subprocess.Popen()`?

Comment: I mentioned the shell=true part [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57495688/how-to-handle-interactive-apt-get-installation-with-python-3-6-subprocess-popen/57496747#comment101612731_57496747). If by line-by-line you mean that it should print as it installs, i can try to makw that work tomorrow. I don't have a workstation that i can use right now.

Comment: Thanks,Continue tmr.  ;)

Comment: I reformatted a little to make it a bit more coherent, and changed the output to now be printed right away without buffering. Is it still working correctly for you?

Comment: Amazing! You solution is so concise. May I know what is the difference between using `PIPE` and `STDOUT` vs using `sys.stdout` and `sys.stderr`? There is a typo in your script, an extra comma in line 20, that needs to be removed.

Comment: thanks for the flowers, and good catch on the comma. By default, `subprocess.run` does not gather any output. By passing `PIPE` and `STDOUT` we can tell it to store all output internally, so that we can use it later. If we pass `sys.stout` and `sys.sterr`, the output is sent directly to the output of the process that called the code. So if you call it from a console, it will be printed to the console right away.

Comment: Can you explain what are the syntax rules used to formulate `msttcorefonts msttcorefonts/{}-mscorefonts-eula {}`?  Also, how did you know `present`, `note ''` and `accepted`, `select true` are the the correct strings to submit to msttcorefonts?

Comment: Researching this was actually the hardest part of this answer. You have to *somehow* learn what the name of the specific EULA is that you need to meddle with, `msttcorefronts` in this case. Maybe there is a surefire way to get, I just stumbled over it while googling for `ubuntu-restricted-extras` issues. Once you have it, you can inspect the license settings with `debconf-show msttcorefronts`. They should be empty by default. Then you run the install, accept the license by hand, and run `debconf-show msttcorefronts` again. Now it should show the two lines that you need to echo into ...

Comment: ...  it with `debconf-set-selections`. That command is just a glorified text editor that accepts a line and writes it into the debconf database. The first part of my answer shows its usage in a simpler form, I only used string formatting in the python implementation to not have >100 characters in a line with a complicated command.

Comment: That is intense... appreciate your helps... Fyi: I confirm your script works when executed from a terminal but will return the exception `io.UnsupportedOperation: fileno` when executed from `idle-python3.6`.

Comment: Glad I could help. But I'm afraid I can't assist too much with the idle issues, my test environment doesn't have a graphical interface, so idle won't run =/
But it probably has to do with using `sys.stdout`, since idle grabs it in order to have control over the output. You could use the old version with the delayed `subprocess.PIPE`s in an idle environment, like [this](https://gist.github.com/a-recknagel/23e1cfd2061e4cf4203a8cc3d9f5c5c8). If it's ok I won't include it in the main answer, since it would look very confusing and specific. And also because I can't test if it actually works.

Comment: Your present solution is great. No change needed. My most recent comment was only a FYI. As is, I have learnt from you (1) how to direct the subprocess's output to terminal or store them as an internal variable, (2) purpose of `shell=True`, (3) how to concisely write `subprocess.run()` and how to deal with EULA (hardest part). I am sure other readers will benefit from your sharing. ;) Gratefully.